# VBA does not place button where I want

Tags: excel, vba

For my work I sometimes want to automatically create buttons located at a specific place, with a given width and height.

My code for this is

```
Sub Add_Button(my_top, my_left, my_Width, my_Height)
Dim myBtn As Object, i As Integer
   Set myBtn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1, 1, 1, 1)
   With myBtn
      .Top = Cells(my_top, my_left).Top
      .Left = Cells(my_top, my_left).Left
      .Height = Cells(my_top, my_left).Height * my_Height
      .Width = Cells(my_top, my_left).Width * my_Width
      .Caption = text
      End With
End Sub
```

So the code is pretty straight forward I would say. I call this Sub with the following line

```
Sub Test_Add_Button()
my_top = 2
my_left = 60
my_Width = 2
my_Height = 3

Add_Button my_top, my_left, my_Width, my_Height
End Sub
```

And now my problem is that this works fine when the spreadsheet is on my main monitor. However, when it is on my secondary monitor (laptop monitor, which is smaller, but shouldn't matter, I guess) the button is not placed correctly (see the image). Since I sometimes have to add several buttons, it is quite cumbersome to manually place them and reshape them as they are supposed to be.

Additional info, which might or might not be important - I have changed the width of all the cells to 10 pixels.

Another additional note, the further I place the box on the right, the bigger is the discrepancy between the actual placement and the wanted placement.

The image: once button got created on the main monitor, once on the right (smaller, laptop) monitor.
[image: added image - once button got created on main monitor, once on right monitor]

Comment: ActiveX buttons are notoriously unpredictable.

Comment: Does the same happen if you reference the column in the `Add_Button` arguments, or would it be suitable, to say, `Add_Button(range("a3"))` then use `range("a3").left` etc?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav it does the same..

Comment: Not sure it will help, but have you tried defining the types of `(my_top, my_left, my_Width, my_Height)` AS in object browser they are `double` Does the same happen if you add like so `Worksheets(1).OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _ 
 Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=40, Top:=40, _ 
 Width:=150, Height:=10`

Comment: Same phenomenon! 
Because you ask, is it not reproducible for you? I mean, i haven't tried it on another pc myself, but i assumed this to happen to others too.

Comment: This does not happen to me (the button is always created on `BH2:BI4`). I have 1 main laptop screen and 2 additional bigger monitors. I use Office 2016, 32bit. When it fails for you, where exactly the button is put?

Comment: See the appended image at my question. I have used the two given subs. I executed "Test_Add_Button" when I had the spreadsheet on the main monitor, and "Test_Add_Button2" when I had the spreadsheet on the second monitor.
I use Office 365 64Bit.


It seems like the shift of the buttons is dependent on the position of the spreadsheet. If I place the buttons close to cell A1 then the offset is smaller, than if I place the button on, for example, the cell ZZ1.

Comment: Do your two monitors have the same Screen Resolution?  Changing resolution (e.g. docking/undocking a laptop with an external monitor) has been known to cause unusual responses in size and placement of ActiveX buttons

Comment: Is there any specific need to add activeX buttons? Or can you use Shapes? I have found that Shapes are more stable.

Comment: I agree with the reply above. ActionX/Commandbuttons i find very unpredictable. I use shapes. I find actionx/command buttons will have a mind of their own and change size and shape/disappear.

Comment: @Chronocidal Is right. And although ExcelDevelopers is also right that shapes are more stable, I have found that they too are affected by screen resolution. I built an entire app whose main functionality was to create grids of shapes that contain data. Anytime someone uses the app on a screen with a different resolution, the shapes are slightly offset even though the positions are hard-coded.

Comment: @Lukas How are your `my_top, my_left, my_Width, my_Height` declared? And it looks like this is not the whole code (I see unused `i As Integer` and `text` from nowhere), is there anything that may delete columns?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue either. Changed monitors resolutions and scale and zoom. Win10/O365 64bit.

Comment: @rickmanalexander  If x-y positions are "hard-coded" then it's asking for it because they are for the current window and not for the "worksheet" area, so it all changes with the environment. In this case objects are created dynamically and are tied to cells: there should be no problems with placement. If the workbook is saved with thus placed objects and the opened in a different environment then... I don't really know what might happen then. The code works for me on all the PS's and various monitors I have immediate access to (about a dozen). Something else is at play here!

Comment: are you sure the Width is 10 and not 9.75 (ColumnWidth = 1.14) or 10.5 (ColumnWidth 1.29)? From my testing even if you set the ColumnWidth to something in between like 1.21/1.22 it still changes it to 9.75/10.5. If that's the case for you then the issue may be related to rounding

Comment: Width is 0.83 (10 Pixel), for all cells. But even with a different width... if the width stays the same, then there still should be no difference, right? 


The Code is the same I have used to produce the images. The "i" which is unused, is because of a copy and paste error, since the whole thing comes from something bigger. But I only have used the Code shown to create the two boxes.

I have tried this with non-hardcoded x-y (e.g. "Range(XX).Left") with the same result - different positions of the two boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I've not had any problems adding a button using this code.  This has worked over three monitors - laptop and two desk monitors.

```
Public Sub Add_Button(Target As Range, Caption As String)

    Dim myBtn As Object

    Set myBtn = Target.Parent.Buttons.Add(Target.Left, Target.Top, Target.Width, Target.Height)
    myBtn.Caption = Caption

End Sub

Public Sub Test()

    Add_Button ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H5"), "My Button"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code;
(it inserts multiple buttons but rather than a height adjustment, we place it rather in an active cell, therefore whatever screen or monitor you are on, i will remain in the sanme place)

```
Sub ADD_A_BUTTON()
  Dim btn As Button
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
  Dim t As Range
  For i = 2 To 6 Step 2 'IF YOU ADD MULTIPLE BUTTONS IF ONLY ONE THEN MAKE THE ROW NUMBER YOU WANT TO THE EXACT SAME ROW NUMBER EG. FOR I 2 TO 2 
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)) 'THE COLUMN TO PLACE 
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
      .OnAction = "btnS"
      .Caption = "Btn " & i
      .Name = "Btn" & i
    End With
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate and provide more details on how to solve the question (including code)?

Answer (score 0):

It is old post but maybe it will help someone.

In my case, button added by VBA, was off every time. It was not related to resolution or monitors, instead position was off because of **ActiveWindow.View** setting. I used **xlPageLayoutView** then and when I reverted it back to **xlNormalView** it started to work again.